# How to change Redux Framework admin footer text?

Tags: wordpress, frameworks, redux-framework

How to change Redux Framework admin theme option footer text? I'd like to show my own text as here in the screenshot:

<kbd>[image: Here is the screenshot]</kbd>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this:

```
'footer_credit' => 'Your Text',
```

to your Redux Framework options file in the $args array.

Obviously change "Your Text" to what you want the footer text to say.

Hope this helps.